# Enable predictable network interfaces via shell on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi4, network-interface, raspbian-buster

Predictable network interfaces on the raspberry by are usually set via sudo raspi-config -> enable predictable network interfaces. Is there a way to enable this option programmatically? I have a shell script that initializes the raspberry pi which should also enable said option.

Answer (score 2):

By quickly looking in the [source code at line 1866](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config#L1866) I found the `do_net_names` function. Here's a snippet of code you might want to work with:

```
if [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then
  sed -i $CMDLINE -e "s/net.ifnames=0 *//"
  rm -f /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
  STATUS=enabled
elif [ $RET -eq 1 ]; then
  ln -sf /dev/null /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link
  STATUS=disabled
else
  return $RET
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for posting that link! I figured I could just do ```sudo raspi-config do_net_names 0``` to enable predictable names.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is actually...
$ sudo raspi-config nonint do_net_names 0

Without the nonint parameter the UI is engaged when raspi-config executed.